# how to let user to input just once using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, validation, input

i have a question here about asp.net

how to let user to change their ID only once after they make changes and submit and when they login again they could not make changes to their ID? However they can modify their other personal details.

how this can be done??

and how's it is like that shows the user already make changes and already submit one time and cannot make changes for second time?

Answer (score 0):

Make the user id control readonly.

```
tbusername.Enabled = false;
//OR
tbusername.ReadOnly = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying that they can enter an ID when they're registering, but cannot change it afterwards, then simply disable the field in the edit form/control.

If they are allowed to change their ID only once after registering, just create a flag in the database and set it accordingly the first time the ID is updated.